# can't get image upload in swift 3 using Alamofire to work

Tags: php, json, swift3, alamofire

I have been stuck for three days while trying to get Alamofire to upload an Image. The idea is that Alamofire will send it to a server with some php code. After a lot of trying and looking on different places, some of the code should work, but the server side documentation for Alamofire is horrible.

The recent update to swift 3 doesn't help much answer wise...

Here is my Swift 3 code:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile!, 1)!

Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "file/jpeg")
        },
        to: "https://someadress.com/post/upload.php",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

This should upload the image to the server, but I have no idea how to properly get the image saved on the server. The server doesn't really need any information of the file, since it will generate a new name for it. It should then send that name back to the app.

I know how to handle JSON in Swift 3 and php, since I've done that before. I also know for sure that at least something gets uploaded to the server, since I have gotten some basic information back.

The PHP code below is almost certainly not good, but it was mostly a test.

```
<?php
// get the file data
$fileData = file_get_contents('php://input');

// sanitize filename
$fileName = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])", '', $fileData);
// save to disk

$fileLocation = "../images/" . $fileName;
file_put_contents($fileLocation, $fileData);

if (empty($fileData)) {
    $response = array("error" => "no data");
}
else {
    $response = array("error" => "ok " . $fileName);
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

p.s. I'm new to swift, so please be gentle ;)

Comment: I fixed it! I'm gonna try to add this to the documentation in a few days!

Comment: Hello can you please give your solution to help the community? thanks

Comment: @Sam Done! Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, sooo. I figured it out. It turns out that Alamofire uses the `$_FILES` function of php. There is no mention of this whatsoever, so let me be the one to try and clear things up. Here is the full PHP code with comments.

```
<?php

// If the name of the image is not in this array, the app didn't post anything.
if (empty($_FILES["image"])) {
    // So we send a message back saying there is no data...
    $response = array("error" => "nodata");
}
// If there is data
else {
    $response['error'] = "NULL";
    // Setup a filename for the file. Uniqid can be changed to anything, but this makes sure
    // that every file doesn't overwrite anything existing.
    $filename = uniqid() . ".jpg";
    // If the server can move the temporary uploaded file to the server
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "../images/" . $filename)) {
        // Send a message back saying everything worked!
        // I also send back a link to the file, and the name.
        $response['status'] = "success";
        $response['filepath'] = "[APILINK]/images/" . $filename;
        $response['filename'] = "".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

} else{
    // If it can't do that, Send back a failure message, and everything there is / should be form the message
    // Here you can also see how to reach induvidual data from the image, such as the name.
    $response['status'] = "Failure";
    $response['error']  = "".$_FILES["image"]["error"];
    $response['name']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
    $response['path']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $response['type']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $response['size']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["size"];
  }
}

// Encode all the responses, and echo them.
// This way Alamofire gets everything it needs to know
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

That's basically it. All you have to do is make sure that the name that you send with the Alamofire request matches the name between the '$_FILES' brackets. The temp name is the name of the file in Alamofire.

Here is the Swift 3 code.

```
// Note that the image needs to be converted to imagedata, in order to work with Alamofire.
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile!, 0.5)!

Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                // Here is where things would change for you
                // With name is the thing between the $files, and filename is the temp name.
                // Make sure mimeType is the same as the type of imagedata you made!
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            },
            to: "[APILINK]/post/upload.php",
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        if let result = response.result.value {
                            // Get the json response. From this, we can get all things we send back to the app.
                            let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                            self.imageServerLocation = JSON.object(forKey: "filepath") as? String
                            debugPrint(response)
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
```

I hope this helps a lot of people who have the same issue! Let me know if there's anything missing or anything you want to know!

Comment: Great comments and explanation.

Comment: what is the self.imageServeLocation referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
 func uploadImage(_ imageFileUrl:URL, encodeCompletion: ((Alamofire.SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) -> Void)?){
     let fileName = "imageName.jpg"
     let headers = ["contentType":"image/jpeg"]
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imageFileUrl, withName: fileName)
        }, to: "uploadPath", method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: encodeCompletion)
    }
```

Comment: what is the imageFileUrl?