# Receiving Image Upload in Swift 5 with Alamofire Using PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to send an image from an iOS app to a server with Swift using Alamofire's multipart form data upload. I am receiving the data with PHP but it doesn't work somehow. I looked for tutorials and other questions on stackoverflow, but non of them are in Swift 5, and I'm not sure which part is causing the error.

This is the Swift code in the app:

```
let imageData = Image!.pngData()!

AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "test.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    print("uploading image")
}, to: url).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

The url is correct and the png data is not empty. This is the server side code in PHP (inspired by the answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348190/cant-get-image-upload-in-swift-3-using-alamofire-to-work)):

```
<?php

// If there is no image data
if (empty($_FILES["image"])) {
    $response = array("error" => "nodata");
}
// If there is data
else {
    $response['error'] = "NULL";

    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $path = "D:/emailback/images/" . $filename;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        $response['status'] = "success";
        $response['filename'] = "".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $response['filepath'] = $path;

    } else {
        $response['status'] = "Failure";
        $response['error']  = "".$_FILES["image"]["error"];
        $response['name']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $response['path']   = "".$path;
        $response['type']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["type"]; 
        $response['size']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["size"];
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

But I in the response I'm getting suggests that `$_FILES['image']['size']` is zero. I'm not sure what the size means. It also doesn't show what type it is. `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` is also empty. This is the response I'm keep getting:

```
[Result]: success({
    error = 6;
    name = "test.png";
    path = "D:/emailback/images/test.png";
    size = 0;
    status = Failure;
    type = "";
})
```

I'm not quite sure what this means and how the issue can be solved. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php: `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR - Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder.` - so it looks like your PHP is not correctly set up to receive any file uploads to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe I see that Value: 6 means that I'm missing a temporary folder, but I'm not sure what exactly a temporary folder means since it's my first time working with PHP. Any help?

Comment: The uploaded file will be put into a temporary directory first when the HTTP request gets processed, before your script starts. The location of that temporary directory must be specified in the PHP configuration, https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

i think their is some mis-match in your swift as well as PHP code such as you are not defining get/post method, encodingCompletion handler in alamofire call and in PHP code you are trying to get image name of 'file' named image

```
$response['filename'] = "".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

but their is no any file uploaded with name 'file'. so replace this line with below line

```
$response['filename'] = "".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

for sending image to server with an iOS app using Alamofire try the below code

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {  multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "test.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        },to: url, method: .post, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        print(response.result)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        })
```

Comment: I think that my problem is that I haven't correctly configured PHP. My code actually works fine once I have configured PHP with a temporary directive. Thanks anyway.